# Position and adjust the size of the video button from Vimeo

Tags: html, css

a friend referred to StackOverflow as a Community able to answer every question. I’m a Rookie to HTML and CSS, but in the middle of building my on website with Elementor. Now I’ve got a problem with my videos from VIMEO on my mobile website. A problem neither Vimeo nor Elementor are willing or able to solve. Can you help and provide me with a bit of code to position and adjust the size of the video button from Vimeo? (Pictures and explanation enclosed) Thank you very much. Your support is highly appreciated. Best, tommy_the_rookie [Video Button Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV5OM.jpg)

Comment: Hi Tommy, please provide a coding effort that you have made so others can more quickly assist you. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on margins, padding and media queries.

The margin and padding will help you adjust the positioning of the play button. The media query will allow you to do this just on mobile phones.

Comment: Thanks Holly. sadly I can't touch the button, only the space of the video